# Encryption and decryption of contents in an excel file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm working on an automation project using selenium python. In this I have to automate the login page. For now, I am reading the credentials of the login from an excel file. The credentials are stored in the excel file in a human readable form. Is there any method where the credentials can be encrypted and stored in the excel. It should again be decrypted while the program reads them. Kindly help.

```
workbk= xlrd.open_workbook(excel_source)
sheet= workbk.sheet_by_name("Credentials")
url = ("{0}".format(sheet.cell(1,0).value))
username = ("{0}".format(sheet.cell(1,1).value))
password = ("{0}".format(sheet.cell(1,2).value))
```

Comment: If you want just to store in not readable format, you can use `base64`: `import base64`... To encode: `base64.encodestring(b'username')`, to decode: `base64.decodestring(b'dXNlcm5hbWU=\n')`. But note that in case someone else have access to Excel file , he can simply decode the data